# Comma or no comma

Tags: commas

I have the following sentence and I need your help:

"The results reveal that in all weeks **(,)** the developed algorithm outperformers the algorithms from the literature."

Do I have to use a comma here? I'd appreciate every comment and would be thankful for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and No.

If you use the comma, then you should put it also after **that**, and in this case, you will have a so called *helper clause* - **in all weeks**, which just adds more specificity to the context.

If you don't have a comma after **that**, then you should not use a comma after **weeks**, as despite the fact, that the part after the possible comma *can* constitute an *independent clause*, the whole sentence is a *complex sentence*, having both - dependent and independent clauses, but not two *independent clauses*.